# how to share the part of the project using git

Tags: git

I have a project which I will share with my team. But I just want parts of the project to be shared.

I have thougth use the branch. But it seems that it does not work.

I have tried this:

```
git init
git add -A
git commit -m "first commit"
git checkout -b share
//delete files unshared
git add -A
git commit "commit at share branch"
```

Do I miss anything?

Comment: Do you mean that you only want to share a certain branch, or that you only want certain files to be managed by git?

Comment: All the project managed by git but only certain files to be shared

Comment: What do you mean by 'delete files unshared`? Are you using `rm`, or `git rm` ?

Comment: I use `rm`.(delte files in eclipse).

Comment: Also, there may be a general conceptual problem with this idea: it essentially cripples git, because you cannot readily push changesets from the main branch (they would create files which you do not want to share).

Comment: You use `rm`? That is a problem. when you want to remove files from tracking, you should use `git rm` (or the equivalent in your git GUI if you have one), possibly with the `--cached` option.

Comment: @kampu `git add -A` stages files removed with `rm`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may create two separate repositories, one for the private code and second for the shared code. Then using [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) make the shared repository a part of your private repository. Submodules allow you to keep a repository as a subdirectory of another repository. This way all files will be managed by git and still you will be able to share a specific part of the project with others.

Answer (score -1):

Just dont add those files to the git.Or make a gitignore file that specifies files and folders to ignore.
[link](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files)

Comment: .gitignoring tracked files is ineffective -- see the first few lines of `man gitignore` -- "Files already tracked by Git are not affected". In any case, .gitignore files do not influence which files are pushed or pulled.

Comment: @kampu : yes and they mention clearly how to untrack those files.

In such a case the file must be un-tracked, usually with git rm --cached filename